# The number of cycle subgraphs in this graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutation-cycles

I have the following graph that is similar to Petersen's graph

[image: The graph]

I was wondering if the number of cycle subgraphs is 792.

Here are my arguments:

Since the graph has 10 vertices, the only possible cycle subgraphs have 3, 4, 5, or 6 vertices. The number of cycle subgraphs with 3 vertices is 10C3 = 120. The number of cycle subgraphs with 4 vertices is 10C4 = 210. The number of cycle subgraphs with 5 vertices is 10C5 = 252. The number of cycle subgraphs with 6 vertices is 10C6 = 210. Therefore, the total number of cycle subgraphs with 10 vertices is 120 + 210 + 252 + 210 = 792.

Comment: The Petersen graph has no cycles of length $3$, the graph in the picture has just one. The Petersen graph (and your pictured graph) has an obvious cycle of length $8$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, it appears it's not the Petersen graph, question edited.

Comment: Your graph has cycle subgraphs with $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$, and $10$ vertices. There is only one cycle subgraph with $3$ vertices.

Comment: @user14111 Is it true that for 3 & 10 vertices, the cycle subgraphs are 1 and 1 respectively, then for 4-9 vertices, it's 10Cv vertices each, where v = vertices?

Comment: What makes you think there will be a simple formula? As far as I know, the cycles can only be counted by brute force. Since your graph is obtained by adding one edge to the Petersen graph, I'd try counting the cycles in the Petersen graph (making use of its great symmetry) and separately counting the cycles that include the extra edge. There are no 3-cycles in the Petersen graph, and just one with your extra edge. There are no 10-cycles in the Petersen graph, so all 10-cycles in your graph must use the extra edge. I haven't counted them all but there are certainly more than 1.

Comment: And I don't know why you think there are $\binom{10}4=210$ 4-cycles. I can only find 2 of them.